# Why is my bufferedReader reading `java.lang.String;@70177ecd` from a text file?

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader

I have a `bufferedReader` which is being used to read lines of text from a text file, however, the only line of text that the `bufferedReader` is reading is `[Ljava.lang.String;@70177ecd` my code is below:

```
private static final String dirToWriteFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/VirtualATM.txt";    //File path for main user detail store.
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(dirToWriteFile);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
String lineFromFile = null;
lineFromFile = bufferedReader.readLine();
String [] lineFromFileToCheck = lineFromFile.split("\\s+");
do{
    for(i = 0; i < lineFromFileToCheck.length; i++){
        System.out.println(lineFromFileToCheck);
        /************* Error because "[Ljava.lang.String;@70177ecd" is being read from file ******************/
        if(lineFromFileToCheck[i].matches(cardNumberStr)){
            accountNoFound = true;
        }
        if(accountNoFound == false & i > 10){
            break;
        }
    }
    if(accountNoFound == true){
        for(j = 0; j < lineFromFileToCheck.length; j++){
            if(lineFromFileToCheck[j].matches(pinToCheck)){
                pinNoFound = true;  //if pin matches exactly what is inputted by user
                break;
            }
        }
        lineFromFile = bufferedReader.readLine();
        if (lineFromFile != null) {
            lineFromFileToCheck = lineFromFile.split("\\s+");
        }
    }
    if(pinNoFound == false & lineFromFile == null){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error! Invalid input length/type. Try again...", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    if(pinNoFound == true & accountNoFound == true & lineFromFile == null){
        break;
    }
}while(accountNoFound == false | pinNoFound == false | lineFromFile != null);
fin.close();
bufferedReader.close();
```

If anyone could suggest what is wrong with the reader and what exactly `[Ljava.lang.String;@70177ecd` means and what causes it be returned by the `BufferedReader` that would be great!

Comment: `lineFromFileToCheck` is an *array*. Use `Arrays.deepToString(lineFromFileToCheck)` to print its content.

Comment: When you print an array, this is what it prints.  It could have been more useful, but you need to use Arrays.toString(array) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not error nor does buffered reader read it wrong. You are trying to print array which doesn't have toString implemented. If you need clarity on the same use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lineFromFileToCheck));//your splitted line that you read from file
```

or Just print line and not the array as below:

```
System.out.println(lineFromFile);
```

Answer (score 2):

`lineFromFileToCheck` is a String array.you need to call `lineFromFileToCheck[i]` to print a String in it

change this

```
for(i = 0; i < lineFromFileToCheck.length; i++){
        System.out.println(lineFromFileToCheck);
```

to this

```
for(i = 0; i < lineFromFileToCheck.length; i++){
        System.out.println(lineFromFileToCheck[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

That most probably means that it's receiving an array and using `deepToString` method.

From the JavaDoc:

`Returns a string representation of the "deep contents" of the specified array.`

So all you have to do is read from the specific element in your for-loop. Just do -

```
System.out.println(lineFromFileToCheck);
```